# Finding files in subdirectories created after a certain date

Tags: sql, linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm in the process of writing a bash script (just learning it) which needs to find files in subdirectories created after a certain date. I have a folder `/images/` with jpegs in various subfolders - I want to find all jpegs uploaded to that directory (or any subdirectories) after a certain date. I know about the `-mtime` flag, but my "last import" date is stored in `%Y-%m-%d` format and it'd be nice to use that if possible?

Also, each file/pathname will then be used to generate a MySQL SELECT query. I know find generally outputs the filenames found, line-by-line. But if `find` isn't actually the command that I should be using, it'd be nice to have a similar output format I could use to generate the SELECT query (`WHERE image.file_name IN (...)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below script:

```
DATE=<<date>>
SEARCH_PATH=/images/
DATE=`echo $DATE|sed 's/-//g'`
DATE=$DATE"0000"
FILE=~/timecheck_${RANDOM}_$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")
touch -t $DATE $FILE
find $SEARCH_PATH -newer $FILE 2>/dev/null|awk 'BEGIN{f=0}{if(f==1)printf("\"%s\", ",l);l=$0;f=1}END{printf("\"%s\"",l)}'
rm -f $FILE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your date into the "last X days" format that `find -mtime` expects.

`find` is the correct command for this task. Send its output somewhere, then parse the file into the query.

Beware of SQL injection attacks if the files were uploaded by users. Beware of special-character quoting even if they weren't.

Comment: ...and how might I convert from `%Y-%-m-%d` to the `-mtime` format? I don't see that in the man page for `date` (this is part of a cron job)

Comment: @JesseFulton `date --date='2011-02-01' +%s` gives you the seconds-since-the-epoch. Subtract that from the current day's seconds-since-the-epoch, and then divide by seconds-per-day (86400).

Comment: So this totally works on my Ubuntu machine, but OSX `date` is different - any idea how to get this working on both OSes? (Or maybe I should create a new question for that? BTW - marking this as the correct answer. Thx)

Comment: @JesseFulton No idea how the OSX `date` command words. You had a "linux" tag on your question.

Comment: No need for passive aggressiveness - @chanchal1987 has a full solution, updating accepted answer